# Div moving a div when item added

Tags: css, html, layout

I have a container div and 2 div's that should be the same height. #Sidebar div goes on the left where as #Content div should be to the right

whenever I add something to Sidebar it pushes down the content Div and am kind of stumped

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><!-- InstanceBegin template="/Templates/2009_07.dwt.php" codeOutsideHTMLIsLocked="false" -->
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>View Applicants</title>

<style type ="text/css">
li
{
display:inline;

background-color: #c5e8cf;
}

a.menu:link {color: #2b2f2c;}
a.menu:visited {color: #2b2f2c;}
a.menu:hover {background-color: #dde504;}

a.side { border-bottom: 2px solid black;
    background-color: #e3e7ec;
    }
a.side:link {color: #2b2f2c;}
a.side:visited {color: #2b2f2c;}
a.side:hover {background-color: #dde504;}
label.side {width: 131px;
        display:inline-block;
        font-size: 20px;
        background-color: #e3e7ec;
        border-bottom: 2px solid black;
        padding-bottom: 20px;
        }
label.side:hover { background-color: #dde504;}

div#header {
    position: float;
    background-image: url("../images/header.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #999999;
    height: 97px;
           Width: 1000px;
        margin-left: 114px;
        margin-top: 10px;
        background-size: 100%;
}

div#menu { 
position: float;    
border-left: solid 1px #999999;
border-right: solid 1px #999999;
border-bottom: solid 1px #999999;
Width: 998px;
      margin-left: 115px;
padding-top:5px;

background-color: #e3f6ea;
}
#menu-content { 
margin: auto;
width:100%;
background-color: #c5e8cf;

}

div#container{

border-left: solid 1px #999999;
border-right: solid 1px #999999;
border-bottom: solid 1px #999999;
Width: 998px;
margin-top:3px;
margin-left:115px;
height: auto;
overflow: hidden;
}

div#sidebar { 
    position: relative;
border:2px solid #999999;
Width: 131px;

padding-bottom: 1000px;
margin-bottom: -1000px;

background-color: #c5cfd9;
overflow: hidden;
}

div#content {
position: relative;
padding-bottom: 1000px;
margin-bottom: -1000px;
border-left: solid 1px #999999;
top: -65px;
left: 132px;
background-color: #f6f4f4;
}

div#footer { position: relative;
        border: solid 2px #999999;

        width: 996px;
        height: 50px;
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
        margin-left: 115px;
}

#body { background-color: #6b86a3;}


</style>

</head>

<body id = "body" >

<div id="header"> </div>
<div id = "menu"> 


<div id="menu-content">
<ul>
      <li style="margin-left:275px;" class="link"><a class="menu" href="/index.php" >Home</a></li>


      <li ><a class="menu" href="/images/header/jpeg" >View Applicant</a>

  </li>
      <li><a class="menu" href="../images/header.jpg">View Applicants</a></li>

  </ul>
</div>
</div>
  <div id="container" >
    <div id="sidebar"> 
    <a class="side" href="#"><label class = "side">  Testing sidebar  </label></a>
       <a class="side" href="#"><label class = "side">  Testing sidebar  </label></a>
    </div>
    <div id="content">



</div>
</div>
<div id ="footer"> </div>

</body>
</html>
```

slightly new to css. Thank you

Comment: You should really post your HTML as well, it will be very hard ot help without seeing it. There's no such thing as `float: top`. Here's a nice float tutorial: http://css.maxdesign.com.au/floatutorial/  EDIT: my guess is you don't account for the width of the border being added to the width of your sidebar.

Comment: What's the point of giving the body an ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be more common of what you want to achieve:

**CSS**

```
#container {
    border: solid 1px #999999;
    border-top: none;
    width: 998px;
    margin-top: 3px;
    margin-left: 115px;
}

#sidebar {
    float: left;
    width: 131px;
    border: 2px solid #999999;
}

#content {
    float: left;
    width: 131px;
    border-left: 1px solid #999999;
}

.floatClear {
    clear: both;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="sidebar">
                Text
            </div>
            <div id="content">
                Text
            </div>
            <div class="floatClear"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

What practically happens here is you line up two left floating `<div>`'s and use a `float: clear;` to rule out that `block`-type `<div>`'s wrap to a newline. They will only wrap upon each other if both their widths (including padding/margin/border(left/right)) will be a bigger sum than the `#container` it's `width`.

By adding more `margin-left` to the `#content` CSS you can put it anywhere you want, as long as there is space to contain it together with the `#sidebar` div.

**Little Extra**

To avoid the classical styling where padding/border make the width of your `<div>` even wider, you can use the newer `box-sizing` feature, where all padding and border width will be pushed to the inside, instead of making the box bigger than you specified in your CSS stylesheet:

```
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
box-sizing: border-box;
```

Comment: this works but now hiding the overflow doesn't.. the border-box does take care of it though, thank you much

Comment: You give your container `height: auto;` which will not work with your overflow. Use something like `height: 400px; overflow: hidden;` whereas the height will fit your custom needs. Even if it succumbs to a parent's height to inherit it's highly likely still not behaving the same in all browsers.

Comment: Thanks a million going to start looking through the tutorials posted

Answer (score 0):

## [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadAdil/ETKt9/)

`float: top;` is wrong;

`float` can be only `left` or `right`;

add `float:right;` to your sidebar and `float:left;` to your container

```
 div#sidebar { 
        position: relative;
    border:2px solid #999999;
    Width: 131px;

    padding-bottom: 1000px;
    margin-bottom: -1000px;

    background-color: #c5cfd9;
    overflow: hidden;


    float:right;


    }

    div#content {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 1000px;
    margin-bottom: -1000px;
    border-left: solid 1px #999999;
    top: -65px;
    left: 132px;
    background-color: #f6f4f4;

    float:left;

    }
```

## [Learn Css](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/011/firstcss.en.html)

Answer (score 0):

The `max-height` CSS Property should do the job.

set the max-height for both #Sidebar and #Content with equal value.

and you can add the `overflow:scroll` if you are expecting any of them to grow height than the max-height.